# robust regions in grid search

Tags: volatility, quant-trading-strategies, returns, optimization

I have a strategy *f* that takes parameters *x*,*y* (for *x*,*y* taking values in integer ranges). I get two grids (of returns and volatility values) from computing *f(xi,yi)* for integer ranges *x1 <= xi <= x2* and *y1 <= yi <= y2*.

My question: what is the standard optimization techniques of determining areas in this discrete grid that are robust with respect to **both** returns and volatility values? The simplest way that comes to mind is given by this pseudo-code

```
threshold_ret = ...;   // minimum required threshold
threshold_vol = ...;   // maximum allowed volatility
threshold_rr = ...;    // minimum required returns stability radius 
threshold_rv = ...;    // minimum required volatility stability radius
candidates = empty list;
foreach (xi,yi) do
     ret = returns at xi,yi;
     vol = volatility at xi,yi;
     rr = maximum stability radius for returns grid at xi,yi;
     rv = maximum stability radius for volatility grid at xi,yi;
     if (ret > threshold_ret) and (vol < threshold_vol) and
        (rr > threshold_rr) and (rv > threshold_rv) then
            add (xi,yi,rr,rv) to candidates list;
     end if
end for
```

Also, assume I have two acceptable regions *R1* and *R2* from the candidates list. For *R1*, let stability radius for returns grid be *rr1*, and for volatility grid be *vr1*. similarly, let these quantities be *rr2* and *vr2* for region *R2*. Given that there are different cases such as

```
(rr1 > rr2) and (vr1 < vr2)
(rr1 < rr2) and (vr1 < vr2)
(rr1 > rr2) and (vr1 > vr2)
(rr1 > rr2) and (vr1 > vr2)
```

what is the reasonable metric to use to select from these regions? What if there are many such regions?